# Thumbnail grid use of figure tag or div?

Tags: html, grid, thumbnails, figure

I want a grid of thumbnails and i was using just divs (.thumb class) with inside a img tag, but i read a article that using the "new" figure tag is better (figcaption etc) . I changed my divs into figure and adjusted the css, but i doesn't react correctly and i was wondering why?

Is using figure tags for a set of thumbnails better anyway?

**CSS with figure, before it was a .thumb class working:**

```
figure {
    background: #eeeeee;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    }

figure img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

figure img:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

HTML with figure, before is was div .thumb class:

```
<div id="content">
    <figure><img src="img/thumbnail_test.jpg"></figure>
    <figure><img src="img/thumbnail_test.jpg"></figure>
    <figure><img src="img/thumbnail_test.jpg"></figure>
    <figure><img src="img/thumbnail_test.jpg"></figure>
    <figure><img src="img/thumbnail_test.jpg"></figure>
    <figure><img src="img/thumbnail_test.jpg"></figure>
    <figure><img src="img/thumbnail_test.jpg"></figure>
    <figure><img src="img/thumbnail_test.jpg"></figure>
</div>
```